# Xam.Plugin.Media picking photo shows splash screen on android

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin Forms, I am using Xam.Plugin.Media for taking and picking photo. Picking photo from gallery shows Splash screen and then pick photo. This issue is on Android Only, on iOS working fine.here is my code.I tried many things and I am stuck on this from many days please guide how can I deal with this issue. I just want to pick photo without showing splash screen just as happening in iOS.

```
             var files = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotosAsync(new PickMediaOptions
                                {
                                    CompressionQuality = 40,
                                    CustomPhotoSize = 35,
                                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                                    MaxWidthHeight = 2000
                                }).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Comment: Hi, I test the code you provided and it worked well on my side. I set a button to trigger the code so when I click the button it will jump to the Select photo Page immediately. I think the problem might be caused by other code snippets. Besides, which splash screen did you meet? Android main screen or app mainpage?

Comment: It shows the screen which is set for splash screen. Picking image shows splash screen for a second and then pick photo.

Comment: And the Attribute for the splashActivity class is here.
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true,NoHistory =true ,ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in Android manifest . In android manifest Android theme was set to the theme that was using for splash screen I just changed android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash"  to android:theme="@style/MainTheme" and Know every thing working fine.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/InfinityLogo</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

```
 <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
<!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
<!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

<!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">#52586B</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#52586B</item>
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">#CACFD2</item>
<!--For button Lower Case-->
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```